What is $\sum_{n=0}^∞ 1/(n!)!$ equals to?
We all know that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n!=e\approx2.71.$$
So I have a question: what is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/(n!)!$$ equal to?
Background and motivation: I don't know, I just create strange questions out of curiosity and because I'm 15 I can't solve them.

Why do you suppose it has any simpler form? I'd bet we can show it is a transcendental number, but there aren't closed formula for every series.

In particular, it is often easy to creat series that converge but to no known number. It is rare we can show it has no closed form, even when we come up with a rigorous definition of "closed formula."

Well, okay, although I would be happy with that too.

You'd be happy with  what? If you want to add an option to your question, add it to the question - a reader shouldn't have to dig through the comments to know your complete question.

But if you want a proof it is transcendental, it seems likely to me because there is a theorem that says a real number that has rational approximations that are too good, in some sense, must be transcendental, and I think the partial sums here suffice. I don't know that theorem we;ll enough to write it out and don't recall the name, but it is used often on series like $$\sum\frac1{10^{n!}}$$

the value of the series is approximately equal to 2.501388888

@ThomasAndrews Roth's theorem? which asserts for any irrational algebraic number $\lambda$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there are at most finitely many rational number $p/q$ such that $|\lambda - p/q| < 1/q^{2+\epsilon}$

@ThomasAndrews : "Why do you suppose it has any simpler form?" : this seems like a fair question if the OP (i.e. original poster) has made a reasonable study of such series, and has therefore learned that if their intuition suggests that there is no closed form solution, then their intuition will typically be reliable.  A 15 year old has no reason to believe that their intuition has the necessary sophistication to be reliable here, so I feel that the question that you asked is unfair.
